# Noun modified by two adjectives; one has a complement, the other doesn't

Tags: adjectives, word-order, complements

When using two adjectives to modify the same noun, and only one of them has a complement, what are the grammatical options? I know that these sentences can probably be rephrased to sound better, but I'm more interested in knowing if these options are valid, not if they can be improved.

> 1.a) He met a rich man interested in politics.

> b) He met a man interested in politics and rich.

> c) He met a man rich and interested in politics.

With another example:

> 2.a) I read a small book easy to read.

> b) I read a book easy to read and small.

> c) I read book small and easy to read.

> d) I read a small [and] easy-to-read book.

The c options are the only ones that seem weird to me. The option 2.d also seems to follow a normal construction as the adjective-to-infinitive pattern naturally appears before nouns, but would it sound natural with other prepositions? For example:

> 3. An old [and] dirty-with-gunpowder paper.

What do you think?

Comment: 1b, 1c, 2a, 2b, 2c, and 3 are *all* "weird" (only 1a and 2d are natural). By default you should probably include the relevant "relativisers" with the kind of "adjectival complements" in your examples: *I met a rich man **who was** interested in politics, I want a small book **which is** easy to read*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Even 2a? I thought it would work like 1a. Now I see that use the verb "to read" twice. Is it the problem or would it sound unnatural with any other verb?

Comment: It's irrelevant that *your* version of (1a) used ***read*** twice (I just happened to change the first one to ***want*** in *my* version, but that's not important). Like I said, you shouldn't make a habit of omitting explicit "relativizers" *(**who was, which is, that [verbs],...**)* with such complements - unless you're copying *specific* forms you've seen from native speakers. And *don't* count usages you see in poetry, song lyrics, etc., as they may not reflect normal use of English

Comment: @FumbleFingers Understood. I think this is why we don't trust automatic translators. Thank you, sir.

Comment: These are too many questions at once.